# SQL Identify Cloud ID's

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am analyzing a data set. Table has 3 columns:

```
-CLOUD_ID (ID Field) example: 121312

-CURRENT_Action (Textfield) example: Started

-MIN_STARTDATE (Date) example: 2016-04-20 17:03:58.633
```

I need to identify the Cloud_ID's which don't have the Current_Action "Deleted" as the minimum MIN_Startdate.

Comment: won't this work :`select * from table where current_Action?<>'deleted'`

Comment: Hi thegameiswar, no cause i need the relation to the minimum(Date). Every Cloud-ID has several entrys, and i need to identify the ones which don't have Deleted as there first action.

Comment: oh ok.Thanks .adding more sample data helps.Can you also look at this link to improve question going forward :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sligtly different approach, pls compare the perf:

```
with x as (select *, row_number() over(partition by cloud_id order by min_startdate) rn from @t)
select cloud_id from x where rn = 1 and current_action <> 'deleted'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use window functions:

```
select distinct cloud_id
from (select t.*,
             min(min_startdate) over (partition by cloud_id) as min_min_startdate
      from t
     ) t
where min_startdate = min_min_startdate and
      Current_Action <> 'Deleted';
```

Note:  This assumes that `Current_Action` is not `NULL`, but that could easily be included in the logic.

Comment: Beat me by some seconds ;)

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff, thx for your fast reply. This one worked and gave me the expected result! THX for your help. JOE